# How to call more then one request to a http-server

Tags: c#, http, windows-10-universal

I can't figure out, what is going on here! Sorry if i do missunderstood some basic stuff - so any help appreciated!

**Scenario:** a very simple windows 10 universal app has to call a http server, which just sends simple JSON objects back. 
I wrote this App, using the HttpClient from the Windows.Web.Http package.
The App has just one button on the MainPage.xaml, and the action is in the MainPage.xaml.cs. So simple as it can be.
Now: i call an async method from the button-callback method (`private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`) which looks like this:

```
private async void callServer() {
    HttpClient Xclient = new HttpClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.thinkitdifferent.de:8080/json/showAll");

    string result;
    try {

        result = await Xclient.GetStringAsync(uri);
        Debug.WriteLine("full result: >" + result + "<");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Details in ex.Message and ex.HResult.       
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }

    // Once your app is done using the HttpClient object call dispose to 
    // free up system resources (the underlying socket and memory used for the object)

    Xclient.Dispose();

    // Once your app is done using the HttpClient object call close to 
    // free up system resources (the underlying socket and memory used for the object)
    // httpClient.close();
}
```

The behaviour is now: when i first call the method, everything is fine. The server just shows the request and the correct information is send to the App.

But when I call it the **second and all following times** - the server does not show any activity. Even with tcpdump i do not see anything on the server on port `8080` (i tried the same with port `80`, same result).

But the really strange thing is now: In the App, everything seems to be ok! No exception or anything. But the result is allways shown as the one from the first call (e.g. the timestamp from the server is still the same).

Anyone any idea?
I am totally lost.

Comment: Are you really checking the current_date field? Because the "date" field works kinda with delay

Comment: Are you sure there is no protection on server side that protects it from DDOS that "ignores" the same request from the same source?

Comment: Yes, if i use postman and try it, i can do that several times without any issues.

Comment: http://giphy.com/gifs/3o6gaQBEbb989Gqm1W

Comment: Before calling Xclient.dispose you didn't call Xclient.close() that is required to close the httpConnection. May be that's the reason your are not getting the data 2nd time. Its also stated in your comment

Comment: @Tourmash: just look at the current_date timestamp, that is the one, the server updates with the timestamp

Comment: Ah... well, there is no close() in the .Net (c#) implementation as far as i can see? So i use dispose(). Am i wrong?

Comment: maybe try to put the dispose into finally statement after the catch block

Answer (score 0):

omg, found it: 
`Windows.Web.Http`ist the mistake, you just need using
`System.Net.Http`instead.
And everything runs just smooth. Strange! And thanks for all the help!